# Increase voting button contrast

Tags: feature-request, design

**Hint:** There is an upvote button to the left of this question.
See if you can spot it on a low contrast screen!

Not everyone has a glossy screen with a high blue contrast. I routinely have to squint to spot unselected upvote and downvote buttons.

Please make them darker.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of that?